# Unable to forward traffic to my local machine port from a DDNS server

Tags: dns, router, web-hosting, portforwarding

I am trying to expose a website running on my local Windows laptop to the external world. My service runs at URL http://localhost:15672. My laptop has a static IP so, the URL converts to http://LOCALSTATICIP:15672. This website is accessible at this address from the other devices on my home network.

Now, to expose this to the external world, I am using a DDNS server. In fact, I have used two different DDNS services (DynuDNS and Duck DNS), one at a time, just to make sure there is no problem with the DDNS server itself.

With both the DDNS websites, I have created a domain name say: TESTDOMAIN which would ultimately named as  TESTDOMAIN.duckdns.org . I have also ran command like following to register my router IP to the DDNS server. The DDNS server shows my IP address linked successfully to the domain name. Even when I ping this domain name - "TESTDOMAIN.duckdns.org" from outside world, I am getting a response back.

```
echo url="https://www.duckdns.org/update?domains=TESTDOMAIN&token=a7c4d0ad-114e-40ef-ba1d-d217904a50f2&ip=" | curl -k -o /Users/administrator/duckdns/duck.log -K -

https://www.duckdns.org/install.jsp
```

But when I try to hit my actual web server from http://TESTDOMAIN.duckdns.org:15672, there comes no response.

So, then I went to my D-Link DIR-615 router as admin and added a port forwarding rule for incoming traffic at 15672 to my router to my LOCALSTATICIP serving the website. Still no luck. One thing I noted is that the rules page does not have option to fill both source and target ports. It only has one TCP and UDP port text box. I am assuming that port 15672 when hit on the router will be mapped to 15672 on the target IP. An example article showing the same configuration for my router model: https://portforward.com/d-link/dir-615/

[image: Port forwarding in router]

Then I added a firewall rule on my local windows laptop to allow any incoming traffic on port 15672. Still same result.

[image: Windows firewall -1]

[image: Windows firewall -2]

Last thing I tried is to create a new schedule in my router to for the port forwarding rule, just as wild guess. That too did not work.

[image]

I am getting the same results for all the tests mentioned above, when I try accessing it using my external IP associated with the DDNS domain name, instead of the domain name itself.

How can I test if traffic is really reaching my machine? Is there a setting I am missing here in the router?

Please help !

Comment: Please do not use wrong tags, your question has no connection to [Google Cloud DNS](https://cloud.google.com/dns)

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza - Sorry, I could not find any tag for dynamic dns and thought Google Cloud DNS is the closest. I see you have removed the Google Cloud DNS tag now. Thanks. Do you know which tag should be the closest to the user community working on such things?

Comment: No worries, everything looks good now.